# Android Permission manager

Tags: android

I am writing an android app to manage permission of a packages for all user install app.

i am able to list all the user install app from /data/app, also the all the packages that an app is using it.

I wanted to know how to modify the permission of the packages of install app?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the permission of packages of other apps using any apis. You will need a custom ROM to do this.

Comment: Root is probably sufficient (versus a ROM mod), but there most certainly are not any APIs for this.

Comment: please let me know how to modify custome ROM.  also is it possible to modify the manifest file.

Comment: please let me know how to modify custome ROM.  also is it possible to modify the manifest file.

Comment: download the Android open source code and tinker with it. But as Commonsware said, maybe you dont need custom rom. You need a rooted phone and call undocumented apis of packagemanager